# Materialize multiple links for same dropdown

Tags: dropdown, materialize

I'm using materialize 0.100.2 and have used multiple card-panels. Each card-panel has a button that opens a dropdown. The dropdown is same for every trigger. I searched for the solution and I even found a problem just similar to mine. But I did not understand the solution that was proposed. The problem and solution I found is can be seen on github on following link -

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2051

My problem is like I import data from backend and I iterate card-panels up to the length of data I receive. I put the dropdown below this iteration so for it to be common for all the card-panels.

Consider 'actionLists' with the data.

```
<div class="card-panel" data-ng-repeat="actionItem in actionLists">
.....
  <button class="dropdown-button btn btn-floating" data-activates="dropdown-example"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></button>

</div>

<div id="dropdown-example" class="dropdown-content">
....
</div>
```

Can you please help me out. I'm quite new to materialize. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, I'd recommend updating to version 1.0 rc1.
There have been some changes since the 0.x versions.

Then you can have multiple dropdown-trigger element reference the same dropdown-content.
See https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look into it. I'll tell if I find it useful.